# background is not working properly

Tags: css, colors, background

I tried everything is still my background color is not working

```
body {
background-image: url('Css/Swirl.png');   
color: #000305;
font-size: 87.5% /* Base font size is 14px */
font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
line-height: 1.5;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean image?? because "background-color" attribute is not present in your css.. Check the image path, you might have to give it as "../css/swirl.png" depending on your folder structure..

Comment: thanks for the help but I fixed it already

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-color: #000305;`

if you want full screen background image use

```
  background:url('images/background.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
```